# How would I add both these rows together in one row with the sum of both rows

Tags: sql, function, t-sql

```
594517  2018-11-30   5.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    8.00
594517  2018-12-18   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    5.00
```

Thanks all for the reply my situation if very hard to explain with out showing the code im dealing with,Basically the fix to a huge problem would be to get many rows with different dates into one row also adding all the totals for all those row into that same one row

column is the ID, date, the rest are total for services

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: How do you add two dates?

Comment: What are the column names and the table name?

Comment: The rows with number other then the dates

Comment: Adding the column and names scrambles my post im not able to added screen shots

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Have you looked up SQL's `SUM` yet?

Comment: The most basic `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` example covers this.

Comment: I guess I can write it the first column is the  ID, date, the rest are total for services

Comment: Thanks all for the reply my situation if very hard to explain with out showing  the code im dealing with,Basically the fix to a huge problem would be to get many rows with different dates into one row also adding all the totals for all those row into that same one row

Comment: based on the small sample data that you have provided, what would be your expected output?   Sounds like this could be solved with a simple GROUP BY and SUM, but you can't sum a date.  So... showing your desired/expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Agreeing with Tim. It's easy to sum the numeric values together, but what about the dates? Is it enough to just keep the latest date and skip the others?

Comment: Before asking a question, it's probably a good idea to read this first.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a table called KingLove which looks like this to try out something similar to what you're explaining on my own computer:

```
ID          date       service1  service2  service3  service4  service5
----------- ---------- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
594517      2018-11-30 5.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      8.00
594517      2018-12-18 0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      5.00
```

If I then run this query:

```
select max(date) as [date], sum(service1) + sum(service2) + sum(service3) + sum(service4) + sum(service5) as [sum] 
from KingLove
```

I get the service columns summed up and the latest date as the date for the entire row. Like this:

```
date       sum
---------- --------
2018-12-18 18.00
```

You could swap the `max` in the query for a `min` if you want the oldest date instead.

It is not very easy to understand what your desired outcome would be, but I hope this is what your asking.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.

Comment: Good luck. You could also replace the `+` with `,` If you dont want every column to be summed into one.

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as the correct answer?